# Classification: Random Forests and Variable Importance

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, random-forest, importance

In classification, when we want to get the importance of each variable in the random forest algorithm we usually use Mean Decrease in Gini or Mean Decrease in Accuracy metrics. Now is there a metric which computes the positive or negative effects of each variable **not** on the predictive accuracy of the model but rather on **the dependent variable itself**? Something like the beta coefficients in the standard linear regression model but in the context of classification with random forests.